# findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog) must not be null with custom dialog and ROOM database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement adding an item to database, which is a string from editText dialog. Everything is alright, except when I press the "ok" button in the dialog everything crashes. I can't really figure out how to initiate the editText in this dialog with the insertDataToDatabase function

It gives me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText() on a null
> object reference at
> com.example.planner3.MainActivity.insertDataToDatabase(MainActivity.kt:75)
> at
> com.example.planner3.MainActivity.showAddDialog$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:100)

MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
    package com.example.planner3
    
    import android.graphics.Color
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.text.TextUtils
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
    import androidx.navigation.findNavController
    import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
    import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
    import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import com.example.planner3.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    import com.example.planner3.model.User
    import com.example.planner3.viewmodel.UserViewModel
    import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]
            setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#59da66")))
    
    
            binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
                //navController.navigate(R.id.action_RecyclerFragment_to_AddFragment)
                showAddDialog()
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            return when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_settings -> true
                else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
            return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                    || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }
    
        private fun insertDataToDatabase() {
            val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
            val task = editText.text.toString()
    
            if(inputCheck(task)) {
                // Create an entity
                val user = User(0, task)
                mUserViewModel.addUser(user)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    
        private fun inputCheck(task: String): Boolean {
            return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(task))
        }
    
        private fun showAddDialog() {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
                .setNegativeButton("cancel") { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to negative button press
                }
                .setPositiveButton("ok") { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to positive button press
                    insertDataToDatabase()
                }
                .show()
        }
    }
```

fragment_add.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">
    
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextDialog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Hint"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textColorHint="#757575"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,TextFields" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at insertDataToDatabase add a arg of type DialogInterface then cast it to AlertDialog

```
    private fun insertDataToDatabase(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        val editText = (dialog as AlertDialog).findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
        val task = editText!!.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(task)) {
            // Create an entity
            val user = User(0, task)
            mUserViewModel.addUser(user)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

and at showAddDialog to make it clear change _ on setPositiveButton to dialogInterface , and passe it to insertDataToDatabase

```
private fun showAddDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
            .setNegativeButton("cancel") { _, _ ->
                // Respond to negative button press
            }
            .setPositiveButton("ok") {dialogInterface, _ ->
                // Respond to positive button press
                insertDataToDatabase(dialogInterface)
            }
            .show()
    }
```